# Can not change the color of canvas bars with audio progress

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, audio, html5-canvas

```
let ctx;
let source;
let context;
let analyser;
let fbcArray;
let bars;
let barX;
let barWidth;
let barHeight;

function initAnalyzer(audio) {
  context = new AudioContext();
  analyser = context.createAnalyser();
  canvas = document.getElementById('analyser_render');
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
  source.connect(analyser);
  analyser.connect(context.destination);
  
  console.log(audio.duration)
  frameLooper();
}

function frameLooper() {
  
  window.requestAnimationFrame(frameLooper);
  fbcArray = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
  analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbcArray);
  
  // const fractionDone = audio.time / audio.duration;
  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Clear the canvas
  
  const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 512);
  gradient.addColorStop(0.15, '#114357');
  gradient.addColorStop(0.3, '#45B39D');
  gradient.addColorStop(0.3, '#28B463');
  ctx.fillStyle = '#45B39D';


  bars = 100;
  for (let i = 0; i < bars; i++) {
    barX = i * 3;
    barWidth = 1;
    barHeight = -((fbcArray[i] + 10) / 2);
    //  fillRect( x, y, width, height ) // Explanation of the parameters below
    ctx.fillRect(barX , canvas.height, barWidth, barHeight );
  }
}


export default initAnalyzer;
```

[image]

> I want to change the color of the bars as the audio progress changes, tried many times but failed to do it, the current code is fine the waves of the 2d bar is visualizing as audio pitch, if any one know the method please help, thanks :)

The green bar is the actual image and the back one is what i actually want

[image]

Comment: The image does not match the code you provided and as such your question *"...change the color of the bars as the audio progress changes...* is very unclear..

Comment: No no this image is what i actually want, the actual image is different

Comment: My guess is you want media progress as a color change. Define colors . `const c1 = "#6CD", c2 = "#8DF";` In `frameLooper` inside for loop use audio's time and duration to get the progress (as bars) and change fill style depending on which bar is being drawn.example `ctx.fillStyle = (audio.currentTime / audio.duration) * bars < i ? c1 : c2;` To access audio in `frameLooper.`  replace `function initAnalyzer(audioEl) {` with `var audio; function initAnalyzer(audioEl) { audio = audioEl;`

Answer (score 0):

From the image you've provided we can spot a few important things:
[image]

- the background should be black
- every bar to the left of the red line should be gray (#454545)
- every bar to the right of the red line should be white (#fafafa)

This can be done with a gradient of course.

```
const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 512);
```

essentially creates a gradient from the top to the bottom. Unless your image isn't wrong, the gradient has to go from the left to the right.

```
const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, canvas.height/2, canvas.width, canvas.height/2);
```

No we need to figure out the percentages for the color stop. It's pretty easy. The whole image is 658 the red line is at 172, so 172/658=~0.26 rounded.

```
gradient.addColorStop(0.26, '#454545');
gradient.addColorStop(0.26, '#fafafa');
```

One last important step is missing. As we want to use the gradient as the fillStyle, we need to point the `.fillStyle` property of the context to the gradient:

```
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
```

Here's an example:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('analyser_render');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let barX, bawrWidth, barHeight;
let values = [];
for (let a = 0; a < 256; a++) {
  values.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 128));
}

var fbcArray = new Uint8Array(256);
fbcArray = Uint8Array.from(values);

const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, canvas.height / 2, canvas.width, canvas.height / 2);
gradient.addColorStop(0.26, '#454545');
gradient.addColorStop(0.26, '#fafafa');

ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
let bars = 100;
for (let i = 0; i < bars; i++) {
  barX = i * 3;
  barWidth = 1;
  barHeight = -((fbcArray[i] + 10) / 2);
  ctx.fillRect(barX, canvas.height, barWidth, barHeight);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="analyser_render"></canvas>
```